# Async Storage React Native import error but I've not used it anywhere

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

So I'm testing my react-native app, but its giving me this warning:

```
AsyncStorage has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage
```

NOTE: I'm not using it anywhere, there are no imports by me but still it gives me this warning on startup

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "tea-share",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
    "@sanity/client": "^3.3.0",
    "@sanity/form-builder": "^2.30.0",
    "@sanity/image-url": "^1.0.1",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~13.1.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-updates": "^0.13.1",
    "firebase": "^8.2.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.2.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.8.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
}
```

Can anyone help.

Comment: Can you please share your package.json?

Comment: @DavidScholz There I added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't use it anywhere, delete this line
`"@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",`
and run
 `"rm -rf yarn.lock node_modules ios/Pods ios/Podfile.lock && yarn install && cd ios && pod install && cd .."`

Comment: I tried to delete the line and ran the `rm -rf yarn.lock node_modules ios/Pods ios/Podfile.lock && yarn install && cd ios && pod install && cd ..` command, but it gave me this response: `bash: yarn: command not found`

Comment: you could install yarn or use npm instead:  `rm -rf yarn.lock node_modules ios/Pods ios/Podfile.lock && npm install && cd ios && pod install && cd ..`

Comment: I ran the command but it still gives me the `async storage has been extracted` warning.